# How to enable jquery to render snappy PDF view laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.7, laravel-snappy

I am trying to implement this piece of jQuery code. All other HTML and CSS are working fine, however this jQuery code is not working.

How do I implement this piece of code into my Laravel Blade file?

```
@push('js')
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert("sabdfjksbfjdsbds");
        var pageSize = 1300;
        var currrentPageSpace = pageSize;
        $(".section-wrapper").each(function() {

            var sectionPosition = $(this).position().top;
            var sectionHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);

            var availabePageSpace = currrentPageSpace - sectionPosition;
            if (sectionHeight < availablePageSpace) {
                $(this).css("margin-top", availabePageSpace+"px"); 
                currentPageSpace += pageSize; //Now we are on new page and its available space is adjusted
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Did you include jquery in your code?
If yes what is the error you are getting? Any more details you can give would be nice.

Comment: Yes, I have added jquery, but there is no error